# Unable to print RTF text having background color using C#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, rtf

I am implementing some print functionality in `C#`

Before actual printing I show the contents in PDF form-

There are some RTF contents which I want to display on PDF which is working well except the RTF with highlighted text (having background color)

ex - [image]

But when I display this on PDF, it looks like [image]

I get the HTML as follows

```
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Some highlighted text</span><br>
```

Which I am converting to RTF using following function

```
public string ConvertToRtf(this string htmlString)
{
   var htmlToRtf = new SautinSoft.HtmlToRtf();
   htmlToRtf.Serial = "10034959528";
   return htmlToRtf.ConvertString(htmlString);
}
```

If I do not convert it to RTF, it sreightforwad display it like `<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Some highlighted text</span><br>`

Please tell me how can I display it accurately in pdf

Comment: HTML, PDF, RTF...I get lost. Now I just see HTML and RTF, where PDF is???

Comment: @Adriano: I am displaying RTF contents on PDF which is working fine. Only background color is not applying.

Comment: Well then how you convert it as PDF? Here we just see how (more or less) you convert HTML to RTF.

Comment: The code to convert it as pdf is very long which I cannot paste here. My problem is "I have a RTF content which displys accurately on PDF except background color"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're using SautinSoft components. I think the best place to ask this question is their support forums.

Anyway you might want to try to check the rtf tag for the highlighted text. If it is \cb you can try to change it to \highlight, or vice versa ...

Comment: Great !!!! I tried your solution and replaced cb4 with highlight4 and it is working.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the latest version of RTF to HTML .Net and now, It works well.
The tags \cb and \highlight are fully recognized.